# Joining array into $PATH in bash on OSX

Tags: path, osx-mountain-lion, bash

Trying to customize the `$PATH` env variable on OSX with the following in `.profile`:

```
PATH=(
    $HOME/bin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/bin
    /bin
    /usr/sbin/
    /sbin
)

PATH=$(IFS=:; echo "${PATH[*]}")
export PATH
```

When this is loaded, I verified the path by doing `echo $PATH` and the output looks correct:

```
echo $PATH
/Users/apple/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

However, it doesn't look like any of the above path works.

```
ls
- bash: (something like not able to find command ls, which is in /usr/bin)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Non-POSIX features such as arrays should not be used in `.profile`, which is the configuration file for the POSIX shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `PATH` array variable name to something different, like:

```
P=(
    $HOME/bin
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/bin
    /bin
    /usr/sbin/
    /sbin
)

PATH=$(IFS=:; echo "${P[*]}")
export PATH
```

I'm not sure why, though. If I figure that out, I'll update this answer.

**Update**: for a little bit more info on this, see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570308/assign-single-variable-to-an-array-in-place).

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Maybe something to do with how bash overrides variables?

Comment: The second assignment to `PATH` doesn't change `PATH` from an array to a normal variable; it's equivalent to `PATH[0]=$(IFS=:; echo "${PATH[*]}").`. Then you attempt to export an array, which is unlikely to work as expected.

Comment: @chepner - `declare -p PATH` after the assignment prints `declare -x PATH="..."`, so it's not an array (question was about OSX's bash).