# Assign single variable to an array (in place)

Tags: arrays, bash

Consider following code:

```
a=(1 2 3)
a='seven'

export a
declare -p a
```

The output (from `declare`) is:

```
declare -ax a='([0]="seven" [1]="2" [2]="3")'
```

So `a` is an array. Questions:

1. How to change second line, so `a` will not be an array anymore, but a simple variable with the value `seven`? I'm looking for a one-liner, without `unset` etc.
2. Assigning an variable to the array replaces only first element, not the whole array. Where is this behaviour specified?

Note: Bash v. 3.2.48 (OS X).

(I've answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568933/joining-array-into-path-in-bash-on-osx/) today, which got me thinking on this problem, and I'm looking for a cleaner solution).

---

**Edit:** I'm looking for a:

```
a=(1 2 3)

/* One line here please :) */
unset a
a='seven'

export a
declare -p a
```

but without doing explicit `unset`. It matters in a special case when `a` is in fact a `PATH` variable (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568933/joining-array-into-path-in-bash-on-osx/) question).

Comment: You **need** to use `unset`.

Comment: @devnull - can you point me to the place in Bash spec where this behaviour is described? (place where it says that assigning simple value to an array variable overrides the first element only)

Comment: Note that a "one-liner" request is arguably outside the **practical** scope of Stack Overflow -- arguing for terseness over robustness/readability/&c. being innately impractical.

Comment: ...that said, I'd _hoped_ that `declare +a array="seven"` would do the trick, but it yields an error: *cannot destroy array variables in this way*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `unset`.

The first quote from the manual (given below) would explain that upon saying:

```
a='seven'
```

when `a` was an array earlier is **identical** to saying:

```
a[0]='seven'
```

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays):

> When assigning to indexed arrays, if the optional subscript is
>   supplied, that index is assigned to; otherwise the index of the
>   element assigned is the last index assigned to by the statement plus
>   one. Indexing starts at zero.

---

> The `unset` builtin is used to destroy arrays. `unset` *name[subscript]*
>   destroys the array element at index *subscript*. Care must be taken to
>   avoid unwanted side effects caused by filename expansion. unset name,
>   where name is an array, removes the entire array. A subscript of `‘*’`
>   or `‘@’` also removes the entire array.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the first value:

```
a=${a[0]}

or

a=$a
```

Since in arrays, the default value for it if a subscript is not provided is its first element value.

If you want to export your variable, you need to keep it from being an array. You could save it on a variable first, unset and reset it like:

```
b=a; unset a; a=$b
export a
```

Or you could do one-liners:

```
{ unset a; IFS= read -r a; } <<< "$a"
export a

eval "unset a; IFS= read -r a" <<< "$a"
export a
```

Note: The latter uses `eval` which is dangerous when not used properly so you have to be careful using it.

Update: It seems that `<<< ""` appends a newline to the end of the value, so we can't use `read -rd ''` to include lines that separate it. However we could use process substitution:

```
{ unset a; IFS= read -rd '' a; } < <(echo -n "$a")
export a
```

Turns out that saving the value of the variable to another first, unsetting it and re-assigning it is still the best way.

Comment: No, I'd still get an array.

Comment: @kamituel Updated. I guess you actually meant wanting it to be exportable, and completing changing the variable to a simple one from being an array.

Comment: can you explain why `a='seven'` assigns to the first element of an array? Maybe point me to some place in documentation?

Comment: devnull provided me with the doc in his answer. Thanks for your help, +1.